# WPF Binding Overwrites Changes made in code

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Suppose I am creating an `ObservableCollection<Car>` in OrderViewModel class. 
I also have a CarUserControl.xaml file. In the corresponding code behind class (CarUserControl.xaml.cs) I have a line:

`this.DataContext = new CarViewModel();`

Is it possible to set a DataContext of CarUserControl from OrderViewModel class?

EDIT: This is a modified version of my previous question.

Comment: Can you post the relevant XAML code?

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of CarViewModel?

Comment: The mechanism you're hypothesizing is wrong. It's not replacing the instance you're giving it. Either you're explicitly giving it another instance of `Car` somewhere, or you're seeing nothing in the UI because you did the bindings wrong. Show enough code to reproduce the issue, and I'll show you what it is. Incidentally, *you* are calling the default constructor.

Comment: I just realized that sentence "When I run the code, I can see that this `CarViewModel` instance is created, however, property `CarViewModel.Car` is null." was misleading. That instance is indeed created, but not used by the binding mechanism. It seems that the binding creates a new instance by calling the default constructor and then trying to populate the fields, however it does not have the information needed to populate them. Of course, I might be wrong.

Comment: "It seems that the binding creates a new instance by etc". No, it doesn't. I told you that can't happen. Why are you here asking questions if you won't listen to what people tell you? I told you that you were creating one somewhere else. Bubba showed you where.

Comment: It was my understanding of the situation at that moment. I was actually looking for a place where I could create another one, as you suggested. Bubba pointed out where I am doing the wrong thing, and I accepted his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is only one instance where I am using the default constructor for CarViewModel, in CarUserControl.xaml.cs

You are also instantiating in you xaml file as well.

> ```
> <UserControl.DataContext>
>      <local:CarViewModel/>
> </UserControl.DataContext>
> ```

You are not binding to `ObservableCollection<CarViewModel> list` anywhere in your code but to the new instance you created.

> I figured out that the binding mechanism is not using the instance I just created, rather it is using a default constructor for CarViewModel.

I am not sure if "not using the instance I just created" refer to the instance in ObservableCollection. If that is what you are trying to do, You should bind to the collection. I can't tell where your `ObservableCollection<CarViewModel> list` is but you need to have `CarUserControl`'s `DataContext` refering to this list.

PS: You code doesn't state what you are actually trying to do though.

Comment: Sorry, this is just a minimized version of the code that I have. My `ObservableCollection<CarViewModel> list` is bound to an ItemCollection via `ItemsSource="{Binding list}"`.

Comment: I think the issue might be that I have created a list of `CarViewModel` (with actual values) from OrderViewModel class, but I set the DataContext in CarUserControl to a new instance of CarViewModel.

Comment: If Your `ObservableCollection<CarViewModel> list` is bound to an ItemCollection via `ItemsSource="{Binding list}"` then you don't need to set DataContext in CarUserControl.

Comment: Thank you! I actually thought that I need to specify the DataContext in CarUserControl so that the binding could work. Now I removed it and it works as expected!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your modified question:

> Is it possible to set a DataContext of CarUserControl from OrderViewModel class?

No, not without violating MVVM principles. One of the main purposes of MVVM is to achieve separation of concerns; the viewmodel holds and transforms data for a view but the view model should know nothing about the view - it doesn't even know whether a view exists or not. So therefore it should not have a reference to the view, nor can it set a data context of the view.

You didn't specify why you wanted to do things that way, so it's hard to offer you a solution. If you compose a new question some guidance could be given.

Comment: The problem I had was I was binding two different instances of CarViewModel, and got unexpected behavior. I wanted to set a DataContext from OrderViewModel class, not realizing that I simply don't need to bind it from CarUserControl. Thank you for the effort, though!